# How to solve the vector equation $\mathbf{r} + \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{d} = \mathbf{c}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given the following vector equation in three dimensions

$\mathbf{r} + (\mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{d}) = \mathbf{c}$

where $\mathbf{c}$ and $\mathbf{d}$ are fixed given vectors, how can you find all solutions for $\mathbf{r}$?

---

So far I have tried the following steps, to show that $\mathbf{r}$ must lie in a given plane.

By taking the dot product with $\mathbf d$ on both sides, we obtain

$$\mathbf{r} + (\mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{d}) = \mathbf{c} \implies (\mathbf{r} + (\mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{d})) \cdot \mathbf{d} = \mathbf c \cdot \mathbf d.$$

Since $\mathbf r \times \mathbf d$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf d$, their dot product is zero, so we get the following (Equation $\ast$)

$$\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf d = \mathbf c \cdot \mathbf d$$

from which we can deduce that $\mathbf r$ (as a position vector) lies in the plane that contains $\mathbf c$ and is normal to the vector $\mathbf d$.

However this doesn't necessarily imply that all points in this plane are valid solutions for $\mathbf r$. I can't see how Equation ($\ast$) can be substituted back into the original equation to somehow eliminate a term in $\mathbf r$ or simplify it. How do you solve this equation, making sure that you find all solutions for $\mathbf r$?

Comment: Cross it with $d$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 direction in space. Assuming $\mathbf d$ and $\mathbf c$ are not collinear (in this case $\mathbf r$ would be in the same direction), then we can use the three directions to be $\mathbf c$, $\mathbf d$, and $\mathbf c\times\mathbf d$. The first two might not be perpendicular. Then write $$\mathbf r=\alpha\mathbf c+\beta\mathbf d+\gamma\mathbf c\times\mathbf d$$
Plug this into your equation, then multiply the equation by each of the vectors of the basis.